# Using nvm, is it possible to have one version of Node.js and multiple versions of npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

For example: using nvm, is it possible to have Node 4.8.3 with the default npm 2.15.11, and another installation with Node 4.8.3 with npm 3.10.10, and how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

(nvm maintainer here)

No, this is not currently possible. The best place to track it is here: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/964